# WordPress can't upload any images to Webserver on AWS Linux

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, media

I have setup my first ever AWS instance of Linux and installed Apache and MySQL. Put WordPress on it, and got everything installed through FTP, although, I can't seem to upload files within WP itself. That includes new plugins and media uploads.

I have checked the perms of the folder 'wp-content' multiple times and set them to 777 and 775 through both FTP and SSH.

I have checked multiple tutorials and fixes for this but none seem to work. I have created a new SSH/FTP user for my Linux install but WordPress does not like private key files and just wants passwords.

I need help! I don't know what to do next and I don't want to mess this one up.

Comment: Ubuntu Linux? My guess is that you need to give your Apache user and group (typically `www-data` for both) ownership over the files. Which also means you'll need to add your developer user to the `www-data` group and give group-write access to it.

Comment: Which Linux? Is selinux enabled on it? If yes, try allowing httpd to write to the required directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debug, I would:

1. Lock down the AWS security zone to allow HTTP/S access from your IP only
2. At the Linux cmd prompt:
   sudo chmod -R /var/www/html 777

(this unlocks your top-level dir to make it writeable), then try uploading through WP again.  If that solves the problem then you can lock back down with 755 when finished and change the AWS security zone back to allowing world access to HTTP/S ports.

Comment: Thanks. Got it sorted. Never thought of doing that.